# Xamarin - Vistas en XAML o programativamente

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Estoy desarrollando una app en xamarin forms y estoy haciendo mis vistas de manera programativa. Mi pregunta es: En cuanto a optimizacion cual de las dos opciones es mejor utilizar?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

No he trabajado con Xamarin pero, por mi experiencia en otros entornos, te diría que es mejor tener las vistas aparte del código. Serán más fáciles de entender y mantener, sobre todo para alguien que se enfrente a ese proyecto por primera vez.

Solo hay una excepción a esto y es cuando tienes que generar el formulario de forma dinámica (obvio), pero para el resto de los casos creo que ayuda tener las cosas por separado.

Answer (score 0):

Si en cuanto a optimización te refieres a rendimiento no te sabria decir.

Desarrollar en Xaml te va a permitir usar Bindings y una arquitectura Mvvm (que para mi es algo maravilloso) y por eso es mi elección, pero en cambio el desarrollo en forms programatico esta más documentado.

Aún asi llevo ya 3 aplicaciones en form con Xaml y lo unico que no he tenido más remedio que hacer en code behind ha sido en un caso que queria un listview no seleccionable. Si te manejas con Bindings Xaml es claramente tu mejor opcion.

Answer (score 0):

Estimado, no hay ninguna diferencia en cuanto a rendimiento se refiere, el compilador convierte tu código XAML en código C#, en lo personal encuentro más fácil usar XAML y para temas de MVVM tampoco hay mucho impacto que enfoque tomes.

Saludos